# to Trigger one pipeline after another and also triggered by every changes

Tags: triggers, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have 2 pipelines. i need B pipeline to run after A pipeline completes and I also need B pipeline to triggers by Every test branch changes. I am not sure if using resources and trigger at the same file (B pipeline) is correct?

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - test

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: A
    source: A
    trigger: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the scenario, it works as expected.
If that doesn't work, then please try to add the pipeline yaml file to `Test` branch, then create the pipeline B from `Existing Azure Pipelines YAML file`.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - Test

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: A    # Any Alias 
    source: A      # The real pipeline name
    project: Basic # Project name if from another project within the same org
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - refs/heads/master
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Pipeline A is deploying something and I can not test it manually, I need to wait 2 weeks to see if it is working or not. I will return to you once it tested.

Comment: @Pardis Sure, you can monitor and test that.

Comment: hi @Andy Li-MSFT , i have tested it. it doesn't work well. whenever pipeline A run, pipeline B will triggers twice. i am not sure why :(

Comment: @Pardis If pipeline A and B are both in the same repo branch, then pipeline B will be triggered twice. One is commit trigger, and another is pipeline A completes trigger. In this case, the commit trigger is not needed. By adding `trigger:none` in pipeline B, it will not trigger at start commit and only trigger when pipeline A finish its job.

Comment: you mean i just add trigger:none at the top pf pipeline B without deleting anything?